# Rewrite htaccess to different domain

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, overrides

I installed magento 1.7.0.2 for multi sites. My previous site is running on drupal6 which I am transferring on this new magento stores. Previously my site is running multi stores with single domain but with sub-directories for different stores. (`mydomain.com, mydomain.com/se, mydomain.com/fi`).

Now on magento i setup multi sites and got separate domains for each. I have setup new domains with relative stores successfully following this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup). But I also want to redirect my previous domains urls to new domains. For example `mydomain.com/se` to `mydomain.se`
 I tried different ways to manage urls rewrite in .htaccess, also in inidex.php but nothing was helpful.

This I tried in .htaccess file

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/se/$ 
    RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:myweb_se]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
    RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
```

also tried this way

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com/se/[nc]
   RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:myweb_se]
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
   RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
```

and tried in index.php as well

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "mydomain.com/se"){
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = "myweb_se";
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = "website";
}
```

any help regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should write the rewrite code as mentioned below to redirect from  one domain to another domain in your HTACCESS file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://mydomain.com/se [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.se/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or simply you can write,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^http://mydomain.com/se/?$ http://mydomain.se [R=301,L]
```